# how to stop braintree to store payment_methode without asking for server side nonce?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree, braintree-rails

I have installed Braintree on our system for users subscriptions and everything works well, except for one strange behave of Braintree which is storing payment method without my server-side nonce.

My goal is to let the user have a maximum of 3 payment methods stored on his customer account.

Here is what I expect each time user add a payment method:

1. server generates and sends the SDK to client-side
2. client sends me nonce
3. server sends a nonce and customer id to Braintree
4. Brain tree store payment method of customer

Here is what I get after storing first payment method:

1. server generates and sends the SDK to client-side
2. client sends me nonce
3. Brain tree already stored the payment method of the customer!

As you see Braintree stores payment_method without asking me for step 3. which is not good because then I can not limit the number of payment_methods which stored in the customer profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

It sounds like you are passing a customer ID into the client token generation. As a result, the Drop-in UI displays a customer's stored payment methods and [automatically stores any new payment methods added by the customer in your Braintree Vault upon tokenization](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/javascript/v3#display-a-saved-payment-method).

If you are using [Drop-in version 1.18.0](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1180) or later, you can pass `vaultCard` as `false` in the [`dropin.create` option](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/module-braintree-web-drop-in.html#.create). You could then Vault the card server-side using the [`store_in_vault_on_success`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale#options.store_in_vault_on_success) parameter or follow your desired workflow from here.